# Are TestFlight apps the same as the finished product?

Tags: ios, testing, beta

This may be an obvious question, but to me it is a little unclear. I built an app using PhoneGap. While testing with PhoneGap Desktop and the associated app it was pretty obvious that this was just a testing environment. For example, any check to see if it was an iOS device would return false even though the app was up and running  on my iPhone. Also there were some strange positioning issues between what I saw in the browser vs. what I saw on the app.

So, I finished building the app and packed it and uploaded it as a beta app sent via TestFlight to my phone. I was pleased to see I was now passing the iOS checks and some positioning errors were gone. I am curious if I can conclude for sure if I fix any issues to where it looks good in the testflight app it will look good with the real published app or if testflight too uses some sort of test-web-wrapper?

tl:dr; I'm going to guess and check my positioning via the TestFlight App, if it looks good there will it look good in the wild?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use TestFlight to make sure your app is as it should be if you are using the same build/codebase for the release application. If you ask me, it shouldn't matter though if you used PhoneGap or some other platform to send out the iOS builds. I have been using HockeyApp and TestFlight together to test iOS builds from Unity and have never noticed any differences. The main reason to use both is to have different audiences on each testing/distribution platform.